# How to convert a string to a "Null Terminated Byte Array" in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, type-conversion

Suppose my string is `"John Doe"`

How can i convert this to a *byte array*?

Currently i just have the code to convert the `string` into a *byte array*, but how to make i into a *null terminated byte array*?

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("John Doe");
```

Thanks ahead

Comment: A null-terminated byte string (NTBS) is a sequence of nonzero bytes followed by a byte with value zero (the terminating null character). So just add a byte with the zero value at the end

Comment: A word of warning: Null-terminated byte arrays are usually required for interoperating with C or WINAPI code. **Converting a string to a null-terminated byte array is done automatically by the interop layer,** so, unless you have *very special* requirements, it is usually not necessary to do that yourself. If you found this question via Google, please consider that you [might have an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661).

Answer (score 6):

Without delving into the details of why you might need this. I assume it's for a serial port, socket or file etc.

You could use:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("John Doe\0");
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3PPlCw)

If you are really bored, you could create a string or byte array extension method:

```
public static string ToNullTerminatedString(this string source) 
    => source + '\0';   

public static byte[] ToNullTerminatedArray(this byte[] source)
{
    byte[] newArray = new byte[source.Length + 1];
    source.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: This will be the easiest way. If the string is anything, then append the \0 at the end

Comment: easy, but pretty inefficient - I guess it all depends on throughput rates - there are much better ways of doing this *if throughput matters*, but then again: often it really doesn't

Comment: @MarcGravell funnily enough when I wrote this, I actually thought about mentioning allocations and Marc Gravell come to mind l say :P

Comment: @TheGeneral it is my mission in life to be that nagging voice inside your mind ("the general 'your'", not "TheGeneral your" - eek!) muttering something about allocations peridically

Answer (score 0):

Initialize array with string length + 1

Set last byte in bytes array to null character should to the trick